# How to get TCP analysis flags in JNETPCAP

Tags: java, tcp, network-protocols, jnetpcap

I am trying to use jnetpcap to get the values from an offline file read for the TCP analysis flags like those shown in wireshark under the TCP header.

I was able to obtain the TCP header packet but it does not contain this Analysis flag help will be appreciated.

Comment: jNetPCAP does not do the analyzis that wireshark does, you would have to code a TCP analyzer yourself.

Comment: and how is that possible from the cap file i have?